# Integer Column or Enum Column for Java and MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jdbc

Few projects, the status column is defined as integer to handle multiple values and the equivalent string value is assigned in the code after getting the status integer from the database.

example, status column defined as integer and values saved in DB is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 1-6. Equivalent string values mapped in code as 1-read, 2-write, 3-delete (String values)

Other few projects, the enum column is defined and the associated enum value is handled in code.

One project uses Spring JdbcTemplate and native SQL queries. Other uses Spring, Hibernate and Hibernate queries

Of the above 2 approaches, which one is the best, efficient and non-error prone approach.

Comment: Are you asking about the database implementation, the Java design, or both?  For the MySQL side, you should either use a MySQL enum column, or keep a separate table for the string values.

Comment: Added tags to increase exposure to the right people. Maybe you could also clarify you question a bit? There should be a clear way to answer your question.